# Hashmap put method wont Compile with char[][] type?

Tags: java, eclipse, hashmap, multidimensional-array

the field.put methods won't compile. I keep getting an error that the type of board needs to be char[][] but it already is. 
can somebody help me with this problem.

```
import java.util.HashMap;


    public class Field {

        private HashMap<String, char[][]> field;


        public Field(Integer xAs, Integer yAs, char[][] board ,Integer difficulty){

            for(int i = 0; i < board.length; i++){

                char x = 'A';
                char r = 1;

                for(int j = 0; j < board[i].length; j++){

                    if(i == 0){

                        field.put(x + "" , board[i][j]);

                    }
                    if(j == board[i].length - 1){
                        field.add(r + "", board[i][j]);


                    }
                    else{
                        field.add(x + r, board[i][j]);
                    }



                }
            }

        }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`board[i][j]` is a `char`, not a `char[][]`, you'll either need to add the whole board to the `Map` or change the declaration to `HashMap<String, Character>`